# Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError, Listview(list adapter) in fragment and these fragment views in tab page adapter

Tags: android, listview, fragment

There is an error for implementing `listview` in fragments of custom page adapter.

The error has caused in ones of Samsung, so i did modify my actionbar(change to just header) and tab page adapter as the custom one. 
As you can see i didn't `implements actionbar.tablistener`.

There is an error message :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: zmnx.com.tripdocent.views.SpotListAdapter
            at zmnx.com.tripdocent.views.FeaturedListFragment.onCreateView(FeaturedListFragment.java:49)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
            at
```

**This crash, we can see it in just only Samsung phone such as Note2(android 4.4.2) and Galaxy Nexus(android 4.2.1). My condition of build, it is Android Studio 1.0.0, SDK Build tools ver 21.1.2**

How can I solve that?

And There are codes :

`SpotActivity`.class

```
public class SpotActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnTabChangeListener, OnPageChangeListener {

    public SharedPreferences settings;

    ViewPager mViewPager;
    private ListView mListView;
    public static SpotInfo spotInfo;
    public static List<SpotInfo> spotInfoList;
    public static List<SpotInfo> nSpotInfoList;
    public static List<SpotInfo> fSpotInfoList;

    private RelativeLayout backLay;


    SpotListAdapter mAdapter;

    HandleJSON jsonHandler = null;

    CityInfo cInfo = null;
    String name = null;
    String path = null;

    String localName = null;
    String type = null;
    String hours = null;
    String price = null;
    String address = null;
    String addressDetail = null;
    String description = null;
    Bitmap bitmapImg = null;

    String tabString[] = null;

    private TabHost mTabHost = null;
    private TabPagerAdapter mPageAdapter = null;

    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM = "selected_navigation_item";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.spotact_layout);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        cInfo = (CityInfo) intent.getSerializableExtra("city");

        Data.setCurrentCityInfo(cInfo);


        name = cInfo.getCityName();
        path = cInfo.getFilePath();

        Data.setImgPath(path);


        tabString = Constants.TAB_NAMES;

        init();

        initialiseTabHost();

        mPageAdapter =  new TabPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mPageAdapter);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(SpotActivity.this);

    }


    private static void AddTab(SpotActivity  activity, TabHost tabHost, TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec) {

        tabSpec.setContent(new TabFactory(activity));

        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

    }

    private void init() {
        getPref();

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId())  {

            case android.R.id.home:
                // ProjectsActivity is my 'home' activity
                onBackPressed();
                return true;

            case R.id.action_account:

                Intent i= new Intent(this, Accounts.class);

                startActivity(i);
                break;

            default :

        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();

        finish();

        Intent intent = new Intent(SpotActivity.this, City.class);
        intent.putExtra("city", cInfo);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        startActivity(intent);

    }

    private void initialiseTabHost() {
        mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup();


        SpotActivity.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec(" ").setIndicator(" "));
        SpotActivity.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec(" ").setIndicator(" "));

        mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);

    }



    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        int pos = this.mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
        this.mTabHost.setCurrentTab(pos);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        int pos = this.mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
        this.mViewPager.setCurrentItem(pos);
    }
}
```

`TabPagerAdapter` :

```
public class TabPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final int NUM_ITEMS = 2;
    private Context mContext;


    public TabPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        this.mContext = context;
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        FeaturedListFragment featured =  new FeaturedListFragment();
        NearbyListFragment nearbyListFragment = new NearbyListFragment();

        if (position == 0) {
            return featured;

        } else if (position == 1){
            return nearbyListFragment;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid page position: " + position);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }
}
```

`FeaturedListFragment` :

```
public class FeaturedListFragment extends ListFragment {

    public List<SpotInfo> spotList = null;
    public static SpotListAdapter mAdapter = null;
    public ListView mListView = null;
    public static final String ARG_OBJECT = "object";
    public String imgPath = null;

    public FeaturedListFragment() {

        spotList = Data.getSpotFeaturedInfo();
        imgPath = Data.getImgPath();


    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spot_list, container, false);

        spotList = Data.getSpotFeaturedInfo();
        imgPath = Data.getImgPath();

        mListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        mAdapter = new SpotListAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(),imgPath, spotList);
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
       mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        return view;
    }
}
```

`SpotListAdapter` :

```
public class SpotListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    int cnt = 0;



    private List<SpotInfo> spotList  = null;
    private ArrayList<SpotInfo> arrayList = null;
    private String path = null;



    public SpotListAdapter(Context context, String path, List<SpotInfo> spotList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.spotList = spotList;
        this.path = path;
        this.arrayList = new ArrayList<SpotInfo>();
        this.arrayList.addAll(spotList);

        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView spotName;
        TextView dist;
        TextView address;
        ImageView img;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return spotList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return spotList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder;


        if(convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();

             convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spot_row, null);
             holder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.down_thumb_img);
             holder.spotName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.down_title_txt);

             holder.address = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.loc_txt);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        FileTotal ft = new FileTotal();

        String extStore = System.getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE");

        String filePath = "/Download/" + path + "-v001/images/";

        String imgCode = spotList.get(position).getCode() + ".jpg";
        String fileName = extStore + filePath  + imgCode ;

        File f = new File(fileName);
        boolean ex = ft.isFileExist(f);

        if(ex) {

            Bitmap bmp = decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(fileName, 180, 180);


            Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
            Bitmap mask = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.list_thumbframe);
            Bitmap tempResult = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mask, 180, 180, true);
            mask.recycle();


            Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(180, 180, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

            canvas.setBitmap(result);

            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setFilterBitmap(false);

            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, paint);
            paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OUT));

            canvas.drawBitmap(tempResult, 0, 0, paint);
            paint.setXfermode(null);

            holder.img.setImageBitmap(result);
            holder.img.invalidate();
        }


        final String sName =  spotList.get(position).getName();
        final String  descr = spotList.get(position).getDesc();

        holder.spotName.setText(sName);
        holder.address.setText(descr);

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, SpotDetail.class);
                SpotInfo spotInfo = new SpotInfo();
                spotInfo = spotList.get(position);


                intent.putExtra("spot", spotInfo);
                intent.putExtra("path", path);

                context.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(String path, int reqWidth, int reqHeight)
    { // BEST QUALITY MATCH

        //First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize, Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight)
        {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);
        }
        int expectedWidth = width / inSampleSize;

        if (expectedWidth > reqWidth)
        {
            //if(Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth) > inSampleSize) // If bigger SampSize..
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);
        }

        options.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please narrow your code to the relevant parts addressing the problem instead of pasting your whole source here.

Comment: Thank you X.L.Ant, there is a point that error occurs in FeaturedListFragment, they can't find the class SpotListAdapter. So, it shows" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError"